# barstate.islast invalidades series[1]

Tags: debugging, pine-script, trading

## Original Question

Apparently, when using `barstate.islast` the values before zero in a series are not returned.

Is this the expected behavior? Or is it a problem?

```pine-script
//@version=5
indicator("barstate.islast invalidades series[1]", max_bars_back=5000)

index = bar_index

countNonNa(indices) =>
    count = 0
    for i = 0 to 4999 by 1
        index = indices[i]
        if not(na(index))
            count += 1
    count
    
    
count00 = countNonNa(index) 
plot(count00, "count00", color = color.blue) // ok

count01 = barstate.isconfirmed ?  countNonNa(index) : 0 
plot(count01, "count01", color = color.black) // ok

count02 = barstate.islast ?  countNonNa(index) : 0 
plot(count02, "count02", color = color.red) // error expected 5000 in the last bar, but gets 1
```

[image: Image of the example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should execute your function on every bar, as stated in the console.
This will work:

```
//@version=5
indicator("barstate.islast invalidades series[1]", max_bars_back=5000)

index = bar_index

countNonNa(indices) =>
    count = 0
    for i = 0 to 4999 by 1
        idx = indices[i]
        if not(na(idx))
            count += 1
    count
    
c = countNonNa(index)     

count00 = c
plot(count00, "count00", color = color.blue) // ok

count01 = barstate.isconfirmed ?  c : 0 
plot(count01, "count01", color = color.black) // ok

count02 = barstate.islast ?  c : 0 
plot(count02, "count02", color = color.red) // error expected 5000 in the last bar, but gets 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the positioning, but I understand that when ``barstate.islast`` is used, it is not possible to obtain the values with non-zero index in data type series. This is a behavior that is not referenced in either the "Pine Script 5 User Manual" or the "Pine Script language reference manual".

Isn't this behavior a bug? Is there a channel to inform the Pine Script team?

Comment: Hmm.. It's definitely possible to obtain `series[non-zero-index]` on `barstate.islast`. Not sure what you mean really. Perhaps you have a misunderstanding of how Pine works. Your entire script is executed at every bar. See [Execution Model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html?highlight=execution%20model). Also take a look at the [History referencing operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html?highlight=history%20referencing#history-referencing-operator).

Comment: The question would be, why the ``count01 = barstate.isconfirmed snippet? countNonNa(index) : 0 `` returns 1.

Why in this context, under ``countNonNa``, all calls to ``indices[non-zero-index]`` return ``na``, considering that all values should be historical bar index, but we get na.

Did I explain myself?

Comment: The function that you call builds up an internal series of the parameter it gets passed. On `barstate.isconfirmed` you call it on every historical bar, so it can build up a history of `indices`. On `barstate.islast` you call it only on the last bar, so the function's internal parameter series has no history, and returns `na` for those history calls.

Comment: This is explained in [Execution of Pine functions and historical context inside function blocks](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html?highlight=context#execution-of-pine-functions-and-historical-context-inside-function-blocks)